# Perl- subsequent hash iterations aren't correctly setting/returning data

Tags: perl, hash

So.  An interesting problem.

I'm building a master script to evaluate some powershell output across literally hundreds of servers, hoping to save time poring through these massive textfiles to evaluate server configurations.  To that end, this one section of the script checks output of logfile settings (sample data below):

```
System_GroupPolicyResults::         Audit Policy
System_GroupPolicyResults::         ------------
System_GroupPolicyResults::             GPO: Default Domain Policy
System_GroupPolicyResults::                 Policy:            AuditObjectAccess
System_GroupPolicyResults::                 Computer Setting:  Failure
System_GroupPolicyResults:: 
System_GroupPolicyResults::             GPO: Logging - Auditing
System_GroupPolicyResults::                 Policy:            AuditPolicyChange
System_GroupPolicyResults::                 Computer Setting:  Success, Failure
System_GroupPolicyResults:: 
System_GroupPolicyResults::             GPO: Logging - Auditing
System_GroupPolicyResults::                 Policy:            AuditObjectAccess
System_GroupPolicyResults::                 Computer Setting:  Success, Failure
```

This little bit of perlscript is in charge of breaking this up and reporting on these fields - all I'm really doing is reading a regex, grabbing some values, and noting if the server hits our expectations (in this case, we should see "Success, Failure" for all of these settings (hey, PCI audit.  It is what it is).. and then formatting the output in a table.

```
            while ($serverdata =~ /System_GroupPolicyResults::\s+Policy:\s+(Audit\w+)\n.*Compu.*:\s+(.*\w)/g) {
                $logsettings{$1} = $2;
                $setflag = $1;
                if ($logsettings{$setflag} =~ /Success,/) {
                    $logcheck{$setflag} = "Good";
                } else {
                    $logcheck{$setflag} = "FAIL";
                    if ($caughtflag == 0) {
                        push @FailedAuditGPO, $srvname;
                        $caughtflag++;
                    }
                }
            }
        #Let's report this:
        
        #First, let's clean up the bad setting that creeps in:
            delete $logsettings{AuditPrivilege};
            print "\tGPO Audit Settings - $auditsettingsGPO:\n";
            printf ("%-20s %-20s %-10s\n","Audit Value:","Current Setting:","Status:");
            foreach $type (keys %logsettings) {
                printf ("%-20s %-20s %-10s \n", $type, $logsettings{$type}, $logcheck{$type});
            }
```

Here's the thing.  If run on a series of files (we're often running these on hundreds of files at a go) - the first output looks fine:

```
Found Audit GPO: Default Domain Policy
        GPO Audit Settings - Default Domain Policy:
Audit Value:         Current Setting:     Status:
AuditAccountLogon    Success, Failure     Good
AuditLogonEvents     Success, Failure     Good
AuditProcessTracking Failure              FAIL
AuditSystemEvents    Success, Failure     Good
AuditDSAccess        Failure              FAIL
AuditPolicyChange    Success, Failure     Good
AuditAccountManage   Success, Failure     Good
AuditPrivilegeUse    Failure              FAIL
AuditObjectAccess    Failure              FAIL
```

But the subsequent tables all have -one stupid failed line-:

```
Found Audit GPO: Default Domain Policy
        GPO Audit Settings - Default Domain Policy:
Audit Value:         Current Setting:     Status:
AuditProcessTracking Failure
AuditLogonEvents     Success, Failure     Good
AuditAccountLogon    Success, Failure     Good
AuditDSAccess        Failure              FAIL
AuditSystemEvents    Failure              FAIL
AuditAccountManage   Success, Failure     Good
AuditPrivilegeUse    Success, Failure     Good
AuditObjectAccess    Failure              FAIL
AuditPolicyChange    Success, Failure     Good
```

What is going wrong here?  Any hints?  I have -no- idea why this is happening.  My code may not be elegant here (and there are likely better ways - I'm a perl user, not a monk) but I can usually figure out an algorithm or an issue.  This one has me absolutely lost.

Thanks in advance, folks!

EDIT:  Threw in a little debug print statement to print %logcheck as it was setting each value; where it's not showing the status, it's not being set. This is the *only* item that isn't being set.

Answer (score 1):

Well!  I found it -

I wasn't reinitializing (undef) the hashes prior to reiterating across the while loop again; this caused all sorts of strange, cascading issues.  Cleaning up the hashes using undef at the bottom of the loop solved the issue.